# Why there is a difference in the display of webpage in Ipad 4 vs Ipad mini?

Tags: html, css, ipad, media-queries, responsive

I am using the media query for iPad and Ipad mini as:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) 
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation : landscape)
```

**Problem 1:** In landscape mode I observe the difference in rendering, where in iPad renders the UI element as expected whereas iPad Mini overlaps the one over other,

**HTML Snippet**

```
<div class="desktopContentFooter">
        <span class="hotline">You can also reach us on our Something hotline number XXXXXXXXXXX</span>
        <p class="copyright">&copy;Something (CRN: XXXXXXXX) All Rights Reserved
            <span class="desktopfooterLink">
                <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener" title="What is Something>What is Something</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                <a href="privacy-policy.html" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                <a href="tnc.html" title="Terms &amp; Conditions">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
```

**Associated CSS inside media query for landscape:**

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation : landscape){
.desktopContentFooter{
        float:none;
        margin-top: 57px;
        width: 660px;
        display:block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 843px;
        left: 678px;
        text-align:center;
    }

    .hotline{
        font-family: AvenirBook_New;
        font-size: 15px;
        color:#1d3444;
        height:28px;
        width:auto;
        margin-bottom:5px;
    }

    .copyright{
        font-family: AvenirBook_New;
        font-size: 18px;
        color:#1d3444;
        height:15px;
        width:auto;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    }

    .desktopfooterLink{
        font-family: AvenirBook_New;
        font-size: 18px;
        /* margin-top: 24px; */
    }
}
```

**Problem 2:** in iPad mini Landscape I get the horizontal and vertical scroll bar with zoomed in screen(I have added meta tag "`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`") seems to be some other problem

Please suggest the direction to handle these situation

Answer (score 0):

The Meta tag you are is correct. But because the DPI/Pixel Density differs between devices you should use the following:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

    /*** STYLES GO HERE ***/

}
```

Be sure to check out this link: http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/